# Does SMTPLIB receive errors?

Tags: python, smtplib

It is highly likely that this library was not built to function like this. I am using smtplib to send emails from my computer. I have accidentally sent emails to an account that I misspelled which means that I received a Mail Delivery Subsystem error on Gmail. My question is how do I check/listen for such error in python so that I don't have to go online to my browser to make sure the email sent.

```
`try:
        server.sendmail("address@gmail.com","otheeaddress@yahoo.com",msg.encode('utf-8'))
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print("Unable to send : %s" % e)`
```

I was trying to listen for the error, but I didn't get anything.

Comment: Well for starters, your "misspellings" could easily be a valid address on a service like Yahoo or Gmail.  Additionally, I just did a test using Gmail and using the Gmail GUI and I did not get an error on the send, but I did get back an email indicating the address is bad.  It is possible that is just how Gmail does it.  If would be nice if you got SMTPRecipientsRefused per the smptlib docs, but Gmail (or others) just may not do it that way.

Comment: Many delivery failures are delayed, sometimes for hours.

Answer (score 0):

you can use timeout in arg options as [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP)
explain it.

or you can replace 
`except smtplib.SMTPException as e:` 
by
`except Exception`